# Create-react-app css modules with typescript: Cant resolve .module.css

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, css-modules

I am trying to use css modules with typescript and create-react-app react app.

I did `import './App.modules.css';` in my `App.tsx` but I get the error:
`Module not found: Can't resolve './App.modules.css' in 'C:\...\testapp\src'`

however, it works with `const styles = require('./App.module.css');`
then I apparently have to use classes (classNames) for my Styles...

If I only use normal tagnames e.g `h1{ background-color: green; }`
those tag styles are not scoped and are overridden by later styles...

are scoped css modules only limited to css classes and not to any other things like e.g tags, attributes etc. or is there a workaround? and why do I have to require them and cannot import them?
Typescript also sometimes complains that no types for .modules.css have been found..?

```
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/node": "^15.0.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "css-modules-typescript-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.3",
    "serve": "^11.3.2",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "serve": "serve -s build",
    "db": "json-server --watch db.json"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.6",
    "json-server": "^0.16.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to update all npm libraries to the latest versions.

Comment: I think I already have, see package.json above

Comment: The convention for CSS Modules in Create React App is `[name].module.css`. So, in your case, the file should be named `App.module.css` (not `App.modules.css`). To import it with Typescript you can use this: `import styles from './App.module.css';`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but it was a spelling error I made in the file name, so check your spellings and syntax once again.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35501452)

Answer (score -1):

Change your filename to lowercase.

```
import './app.modules.css'
```

Comment: This didn't work